# Why is jquery-ajax submitting form multiple times?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have read this: [jQuery ajax form submitting multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025185/jquery-ajax-form-submitting-multiple-times)

It didn't help.

If i type something on form and click the submit button then it sends one request. Second time if i type something and click it sends two requests. Third time it sends three requests and so on. Why is this? Did i do any mistake in jquery code?

Here is my code:

index.php =>

```
<div id="id_div_1" class="cl_div_comment_container"></div>
<form id="id_form_1" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="nm_hidden_post_id">
<textarea class="cl_textarea_comment" style="resize:none;" rows="1" cols="50" name="nm_comment_content"></textarea>
<input class="cl_submit_comment" type="submit" value="Comment" name="nm_submit_comment">
</form>
```

javascript.js =>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('hello');
    $('input[name="nm_submit_comment"]').on('click',function(){
        var frm = $(this).closest("form")[0];
        var frm_id = $(frm).attr("id");
        var frm_id_splitted = frm_id.split("_");
        var frm_id_splitted_2 = frm_id_splitted[2];
        console.log($('div#id_div_' + frm_id_splitted_2));
        $(frm).on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            frm_serialized = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(frm_serialized);

            $.ajax({
                url: "save-comment.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: frm_serialized,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('div#id_div_' + frm_id_splitted_2).append(data);
                }
            });

        });

    });

});
```

save-comment.php =>

```
<?php

if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}    

echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: You can avoid this line; $(frm).on('submit',function(e){ }

Comment: your adding a new form  submit handler after each click

Comment: each ajax call is also evaluating the same js file again on each click. therefore, two click handlers and two ajax calls, then three, then four, etc...

Comment: No need to make submit `bind` just `serialize` your nearest form and make `ajax call`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are registering the event for form `submit` inside the code you have for the `click` event on the button. So every time you click the button, it will keep adding the event over and over.

This should be good enough.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('input[name="nm_submit_comment"]').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var frm = $(this).closest("form");
        var frm_id = frm.attr("id");
        var frm_id_splitted = frm_id.split("_");
        var frm_id_splitted_2 = frm_id_splitted[2];

        var frm_serialized = frm.serialize();

        $.ajax({
                url: "save-comment.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: frm_serialized,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('div#id_div_' + frm_id_splitted_2).append(data);
                }
        });

   });

});
```

Comment: Great! I had the same issue: submit form inside of a datatable button click. Every time the click was performed, the submit event has increased. Now, with this solution, it works fine!

Comment: I pulled lot of hair from head thanks to this. I also had form.submit inside click event and it was duplicating this all the time when it was clicked. I learned my lesson.

Answer (score 7):

Try `one` then `on`

```
$("#id_form_1").one('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    frm_serialized = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(frm_serialized);

    $.ajax({
        url: "save-comment.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: frm_serialized,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('div#id_div_' + frm_id_splitted_2).append(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Also **no need** to make submit `bind` just `serialize` your nearest form and make `ajax` call. You are binding event inside and event performs `multiple binding`.

Comment: This worked great for me where a `click` opens a modal window and then within that modal is a form for the user to `submit`. Therefore the `on('submit')` was changed to `one('submit')` for it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).off().on("click","#submit",(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
}
```